# Flutter Firebase AuthStateChange Listener never gets called for same user

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In my code I have the following:

```dart
    late final FirebaseApp app;
    Future<void> initFirebase() async {
      app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: app);
    }
    //...some code omitted for brevity
    auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) async {
          final authenticatedUser = user;
          //Transition to home screen
    }
```

Unfortunately If I login with me@gmail.com and then logs out, once I log in back with me@gmail.com again `authStateChanges` never gets called again, as a result my app is left stuck with no idea of what screen to transition to.

How can I fix this please?